# missing right parenthesis (ORA-00907) while updating the record

Tags: python, python-3.x, sql-update, cx-oracle

I'm struggling with missing parenthesis error. Part of my code below:

```python
for r in Records:
    update_query = F"UPDATE {Schema}.{table} SET ("
    values_list = list()

    for c, v in zip(columns[1:], val_list[1:]):
        values_list.append(F"{c}={v}")
    update_query += ", ".join(values_list)
    update_query += ") WHERE SOME_ID=:1"
    cursor.execute(update_query, r)
```

From above the query is as follows:

```
UPDATE MY_SHEMA.MY_TABLE SET (VAL2=:2, VAL3=:3, VAL4=:4, VAL5=:5, VAL6=:6, VAL7=:7, VAL8=:8, VAL9=:9, VAL10=:10, VAL11=:11, VAL12=:12, VAL13=:13, VAL14=:14, VAL15=:15, VAL16=:16, VAL17=:17) WHERE VAL1=:1
```

The record (r) looks as follows:

```
[11111, 'some_string', 'some longer string', 4, 'another', 1, '', datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 16, 1, 25, 38), 'some-other-string', 'another string', 7.5, 5.5, 'some:complex/string/with/some/:values', 9.8, 8.5, 'another:complex/string/with/some/:values', datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 4, 17, 43, 23)]
```

When I insert similar values it works fine. I simply cannot update my records. No idea where that parenthesis is missing. I tried to remove `()` from between `SET` and `WHERE`. It didn't help resulting in the very same error. I'm guessing it's somehow related to the data types in the record. No idea however, why it works while inserting in similar way. Where
`str_columns is list of all columns` and
`value_string is list like [:1,:2,:3...]`

```python
SQL = 'insert into ' + Schema + '.' + table + ' (' + str_columns + ') values (' + value_string + ')'
    logger.debug('SQL statement: %s', SQL)
    cursor.executemany(SQL, values, batcherrors=True)
```

**EDIT:** I verified the record when it's being inserted and wen it's being updated. They look the same, they have the same objects inside, written in the same way.

I know it's not the best way to do db operations with python. This is a very old script and I need to fix the update thing. Not going to write it from the scratch.

Comment: If you were able to see the actual final SQL statement that it's trying to execute, then the issue would (hopefully!) be obvious.  Can you log the statement by hand, or is there an SQL debug setting that will log it?

Comment: @John Gordon I'm logging update_query variable and content of r (list that is passes to the execute method). Not sure if cx_oracle cursor may log more

Comment: Actually I think the problem is much simpler -- you shouldn't be using parentheses at all!  The syntax should be like `UPDATE tablename SET field=:1 WHERE ID=:2`.  The "missing right parenthesis" error is misleading in this case.  You do need parentheses for `INSERT INTO`, but not for `UPDATE ... SET`.

Comment: Like I wrote in my original post
`I tried to remove () from between SET and WHERE. It didn't help resulting in the very same error.`

Comment: Actually , I just verified again the previous statement. It does crash w/o `()`, but with another error. Now it says, the data type is inconsistent. Which probably indicates execute method doesn't unpack values in a proper way. 

in the `update_query` I use `SET VAL2=:2, VAL3=:3... where VAL1=:1` maybe that's wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so basically parenthesis were not an issue as mentioned by John Gordon. Once I removed them there were error about data inconsistency. Started digging that and I concluded there is something wrong with the loop that creates `VALn=:n`. I decided to remove the ID key from there and from the record that is being passed to the execute method. I saved it aside and used it in `WHERE` clause. The loop looks as follows right now (Added val_list definition):

```python
##########################
#     Somewhere above    #
##########################
for i in range(1, len(columns)+1):
    val_list.append(':'+ str(i))

#######
#(...)#
#######


for r in Records:
    SOME_ID = r.pop(0)  # Remove some_id from the record. The record is now shorter
    update_query = F"UPDATE {Schema}.{table} SET "
    values_list = list()

    for c, v in zip(columns[1:], val_list[:-1]):  # take column names w/o SOME_ID and one less :n value (as recrod is shorter now)
        values_list.append(F"{c}={v}")

    update_query += ", ".join(values_list)
    update_query += F" WHERE SOME_ID='{SOME_ID}'"
    cursor.execute(update_query, r)
```

Final conclusion:
I guess I got confused by all these values and fact I wanted to pass the `WHERE` clause argument from the record itself by `:n`. Probably I could fix what I had, but got stuck and decided to try different approach. It works :)